# How to make numbers fit in a Word table column

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I have a Word table where the numbers look like this (see the "B.I." column):

[image: Numbers look all wrong]

As you can see, the numbers fit in the column perfectly fine, and yet Word keeps wrapping them. In order to make the numbers appear horizontally, I have to widen that column:

[image: Column absurdly wide]

How can I make the numbers fit in a column that obviously has enough space for them?

I already selected the entire column's cells, set "Cell margins" to 0, and unchecked "Wrap text". Word ignores me.

EDIT: you can download a sample file here:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/13m1jm6aiEUiKPx5zFbFTVLWRWeJtftoC/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106065379542109181048&rtpof=true&sd=true

There's only the table, but as you can see, the error still happens.

Comment: Can you give us a link to a sample document with the problem so we do not have to try to reproduce it to fix it? Edit your question, please.

Comment: Maybe you'll see more unwanted characters there. See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/show-or-hide-tab-marks-in-word-84a53213-5d02-404a-b022-09cae1a3958b

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any tabs or spaces before the number? Or is a margin set on that cell?

Comment: @CharlesKenyon: the document has other propietary info that I cannot really share, so I didn't really think about that option. I've tried copying and pasting the table to a new blank document and it still happens, so I'll put a link now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the paragraph indents in your columns. They are currently set far to the right.

[image: screenshot including ruler]

To handle the entire column rather than a single cell as in the screenshot, select the column first.

Here is a link to the [Indents](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/basic_formatting.htm#Indents) part of my page on Basic Formatting.

Here is a link to the Microsoft Help Page on [Using the Ruler](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-the-ruler-in-word-775014ca-7bb9-4b75-ba19-4478c4a836d1). Scroll down the page for information about the various indents and marks.